# Call a sub using a string-variable

Tags: sql, vba, outlook

I have a SQL-database in which I list conditions that mails have to meet.

For every mail that I receive the database is searched, and if the conditions of one of the records are fulfilled, another Sub shall be called for the Mail. Which Sub is to be executed is defined in the database as well.

Everything works fine, but I am not able to call the Sub.

```
Sub automatik_sql() 
'VERWEIS auf ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library notwendig'
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olitem As Outlook.MailItem
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set olitem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem

Dim con As ADODB.connection
Dim rec As ADODB.recordset
Dim MySQL As String
Dim ausloeser As Boolean
ausloeser = True
MySQL = "SELECT MA_Index, beding_body, beding_subj, aktion FROM Mail_Automatik where (empfaenger = '" & olitem.To & "' and absender ='" & olitem.SenderEmailAddress & "')"
Set con = New ADODB.connection
con.Open "Provider=sqloledb; Data Source=meinedaten; Initial Catalog=STAMMDATEN; INTEGRATED SECURITY=sspi;"
Set rec = con.Execute(MySQL)
While Not rec.EOF
If Not IsNull(rec.Fields("beding_body").Value) Then
  If InStr(olitem.Body, rec.Fields("beding_body").Value) = 0 Then ausloeser = False
End If
If Not IsNull(rec.Fields("beding_subj").Value) Then
    If InStr(olitem.Subject, rec.Fields("beding_subj").Value) = 0 Then ausloeser = False
End If
```

and now i have the Problem:

```
If ausloeser = True Then Call rec.Fields("aktion")
rec.movenext
Wend
End Sub
```

As I am working on a german-language machine I only have the error (poping up at the start of the Sub) in german:

> Fehler beim kompilieren: Unzulässige Verwendung einer Eigenschaft
>   Translation: "failed to compile: illegal use of a property "

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: It might be worth adding an english translation of that error:  "Compiler Error: Disallowed use of a Property"

Comment: `Fehler beim kompilieren: Unzulässige Verwendung einer Eigenschaft` translates to `Failed to compile: illegal use of a property`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`If ausloeser = True Then Call rec.Fields(aktion)`

RecordSet.Fields is a property -- a collection of fields in the recordset.  It's not a *method*, so it can't be called as it's being used here.

I suspect that the intent is to call some other method, and pass it the content of the `aktion` field?  If so the syntax would be `Then Call othermethod(rec.Fields("aktion"))`

Comment: Hi Joe, you are absolutely right, that was wrong. The bad news is, changing this does not change the error message.

Comment: If you're still calling `rec.Fields` as a method, you will still get that error...

Comment: as it does not seem possibly to call another function I changed the code; instead of having the line causing the Problems I put 

<code>        Select Case rec.Fields("aktion")
            Case "test123"
                Call test123(olitem)
            Case "weiterleiten_poll"
                Call weiterleiten_poll(olitem)
            Case "er_adresse"
                Call geht_an_er_adresse_daher_yambs_direkt(olitem)
        end select </code>

Of course a bit longer but working!
Thanks for your Input - sorry no idea how to put code in here...